# Parent styles in a nested class but only using one class name on element - SASS

Tags: css, sass

So, I'm having a look at some naming conventions. I'd like to try and have some class names similar to: `.block(red)`.

So my HTML would look like:

`<div class="block(red)"></div>`

my *compiled* css should look like:

```
.block(red) {
    padding: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

So i would like my SASS to look something like:

```
.block {
  padding: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  &\(red\) {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Obviously as the `(red)` part of the class name is only extending the parent class name it won't bring in the styles from `.block`, I could `@extend .block` within the `(red)` class but that will be a little messy over time.

So, is there any way you guys can think of, that allows me to write SASS like my above example while only having to write one class on my element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>**First of all, [parentheses aren't allowed in CSS class names](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)**, they're reserved for certain selectors.</strike>
Update: escaping the parentheses using `\(\)` does seem to be allowed and works.

If you want to do something like this, you could use [OOCSS, BEM, SMACSS, ACSS or something similar](http://clubmate.fi/oocss-acss-bem-smacss-what-are-they-what-should-i-use/).

---

### Update:

If you really only want to use one CSS class, you could use a **SCSS `@mixin`** like this:

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/grrtbrtr/pen/KVeOja

**SCSS**

```
@mixin modulify($selection-modifier) {
  $self: &;
  &\(#{$selection-modifier}\) {
    @content;
    @extend #{$self};
  }
}

.block {
  padding: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  @include modulify('red') {
    background: red;
  }

  @include modulify('blue') {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="block(red)"></div>
<div class="block(blue)"></div>
```

For me, it keeps the SCSS code clean, and allows you to use only 1 CSS class in your HTML.

Comment: I did think that they were not allowed. Does is make any difference that i'm escaping the character? I've just checked  `.color\(red\) { color: red; }` on the W3 CSS Validator and It's flagged no issues!

Comment: Indeed, escaping special characters in the selector will work, my bad...

Comment: Okay cool, But I still don't think this is _quite_ what I'm looking for yet, maybe it's just not possible, I may need to look into a simple function or mixin.